# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource - Ionic 2

Tags: http, angular, xmlhttprequest, ionic2

I have a rest web service and now I want to make a post request from ionic 2 frontend app to authentication rest method.

On my login component I have:

```
...this._restClient.post(
                'authentication',
                body,
                (data) => this.handleSuccessAuthenticate(data),
                (data) => this.handleErrorAuthenticate(data)
            );...
```

On my provider my _restClient code is:

```
public post(resource: string, data: Object, onSuccess: restClient, onError: callbackRestClient) {
        var httpResult: Observable<Response>;


        if (data === null) {
            httpResult = this._http.post(this.getUrl(resource), '{}', { headers: this.getHeaders() });
        } else {
            httpResult = this._http.post(this.getUrl(resource), JSON.stringify(data), { headers: this.getHeaders() });
        }


        this.handleResult(httpResult, onSuccess, onError);
    }
```

I also have a private method to set headers:

```
   private getHeaders() {
        var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
        headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
        headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token");

        return headers;
    }
```

I have the classic message:

```
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
```

What I´m doing wrong?

Comment: See this a great Thierry's answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36768418/how-to-make-cors-enabled-http-requests-in-angular-2/36768488#36768488

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, it's server-side issue and not an Angular2 one. The preflighted OPTIONS request need to return a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in its response.

See these articles for more details:

- http://restlet.com/blog/2015/12/15/understanding-and-using-cors/
- http://restlet.com/blog/2016/09/27/how-to-fix-cors-problems/

Comment: Is there anything I can do so we can bypass it at the client side because I don't own the server.