# POST method not working in Angular2

Tags: java, rest, angular, angular2-http

I am new in Angular2. I am trying to call simple java REST call from Angular2. When I am posting data I am not getting error at all but my java post method is not called.

Angular2 POST-

```
let emplyee = JSON.stringify(this.object);
    let url = 'http://localhost:8080/rest-app/rest/employeeService/insertEmployee';
    console.log("Data: " + emplyee);
    let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
    this.http.post(url, emplyee, options);
```

Java POST method-

```
@POST
@Path("/insertEmployee")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String insertEmployee(String employee) {
    logger.debug("Employee: " + employee);
    return "Hello";
}
```

Comment: what is the response you get? add `.subscribe(res => console.log(res))` right after `this.http.post()` to `console.log` the response.

Comment: @Supamiu thnx for response, this response I got, **Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the preflight resuest doesn't pass. 
You have to allow CORS requests in your Java API (you have to add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin *` header, see your API lib doc to know how to add it).

That's why you get an error in subscribe, because your preflight request doesn't pass.

EDIT: see [How to make CORS-enabled HTTP requests in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36768418/how-to-make-cors-enabled-http-requests-in-angular-2) for more explanations on the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add subscribe like this-

```
    this.http.post(url, emplyee, options)
    .subscribe((response) => {
            //handle response here
    })
    .catch(this.handleError);
```

If you want to use promise then use it like this-

```
    this.http.post(url, employee, options)
        .toPromise()
        .then(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.handleError);
```