# Access Control Allow Origin issue in Angular 2 http services

Tags: javascript, angular, cors, angular-services, angular-http

I facing issue with fetching data from my laravel server.

This is client side code:

```
private surveysUrl = 
'http://107.170.59.79/services/public/api/v1/countries';
private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

constructor(private http: Http) { }

getSurveys(): Promise<Survey[]> {
return this.http.get(this.surveysUrl)
   .toPromise()
   .then(response => response.json() as Survey[])
   .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

But I am receiving as error as:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load 
   {{link set in variable "surveysUrl"}}. The 'Access-Control-
   Allow-Origin' header has a value '{{Some random link}}' that is not 
   equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore 
   not allowed access.

How can I fix this error?

PS: I am not allowed to post more than two links so I had to remove links from the error message. I have replaced it with {{ }} to make it readable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make CORS-enabled HTTP requests in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36768418/how-to-make-cors-enabled-http-requests-in-angular-2)

Comment: It's only *http://49.248.126.222:8282/* that has access, you need to change that to allow your localhost, or then allow all. This has to be done server side, not Angular as you asked below.

Comment: Thanks @AJT_82. I will make the changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using apache then you need to allow the origin access i.e.

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

include this in .htaccess file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but can you please let me know if I can handle it from Angular.

Comment: Hi @RumSmeagolRun this is something to be done at server side. (i.e the one who is creating the API end point for you)