# Angular 2 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' Issue when requesting API call

Tags: angular, http, header, request, cross-domain

Hey I am facing this Issue when I am Hitting API from my angular 2 application

No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

How to send header request in get method ?

Comment: You need to implement CORS on the server side. There are lots of samples out there on SO and elsewhere.

Comment: Similar question was already asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36768418/how-to-make-cors-enabled-http-requests-in-angular-2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make CORS-enabled HTTP requests in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36768418/how-to-make-cors-enabled-http-requests-in-angular-2)

Comment: But i have 2 different api with different endpoints, with one it works proper, and with other it returns cors error