# Local hosted API not accessible from Angular 4 http

Tags: php, angular, slim

I've got a very strange issue.

- local hosted PHP Slim App using XAMPP (localhost:4040)
- local hosted Angular 4 App using CLI (localhost:4200)

Making API Requests using "Postman" and browser is no problem, everything works fine. 
Now I'm integrating the requests into my Angular app using `import { Headers, Http } from '@angular/http';` and observables.

```
     const requestUrl = 'http://localhost:4040/register';
     const headers = new Headers({
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
     });

     this.http
        .get(requestUrl, {headers: headers})
        .map(response => response.json())
        .subscribe(result => {
           console.log(result);
        }, error => {
           console.log(error);
        });
```

The request always fails with:

> Failed to load http://localhost:4040/register: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.

But: I am definitely sending these headers!

```
    public static function createJsonResponseWithHeaders($response, $requestedData)
{
    // Add origin header
    $response = $response->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    $response = $response->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET');

    // Add json response and gzip compression header to response and compress content
    $response = $response->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    $response = $response->withHeader('Content-Encoding', 'gzip');

    $requestedData = json_encode($requestedData, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    $response->getBody()->write(gzencode($requestedData), 9);

    if (!$requestedData || (count($requestedData) === 0)) {
        return $response->withStatus(404)->write('Requested data not found or empty! ErrorCode: 011017');
    }

    return $response;
}
```

What I already tried for solving:

- Run Slim App inside a Docker Container to get a different origin than localhost - same behaviour
- Add allow-origin-header right on top of the index.php
  `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` - same behaviour

Answer (score 1):

Your requests are blocked because of CORS not being set up properly. There are other questions that address this, e.g. [How to make CORS enabled requests in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36768418/how-to-make-cors-enabled-http-requests-in-angular-2?rq=1)

What you should ideally look at using is a proxy that forwards your requests to the API, the latest Angular CLI comes with support for a dev proxy (see https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md) out of the box. You set it up with a proxy.conf.json that could look like this:

`{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:4040",
    "secure": false,
    "pathRewrite": {"^/api" : ""}
  }
}`

What this piece of code does is any requests from Angular to a URI matching /api will be forwarded to localhost:4040.

Note that you will also need to figure out how your app will talk to the API server in a non-dev environment. I have been happy with using Nginx to serve Angular files, and act as  proxy for the API.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my bad. The solution is simple:

The "Cache-control" header in the request seems to be not allowed, although it worked fine when testing the api with Postman. 
I removed the header from the request and everything worked well.

Comment: Use cors middleware, you aren't accounting for OPTIONS preflight requests